# Failed to set permissions of path: ..\taskTracker\cyg_server to 0700

Tags: ssh, unix, java, cygwin, hadoop

While running a job in Cygwin in Hadoop cluster, the permission failed.

```
$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar wordcount inputwords outputwords2
Patch for HADOOP-7682: Instantiating workaround file system
13/09/19 16:37:39 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1       
13/09/19 16:37:41 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201309191635_0002
13/09/19 16:37:42 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/09/19 16:37:43 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201309191635_0002_m_000002_0,     Status : FAILED
Error initializing attempt_201309191635_0002_m_000002_0:
java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path:  \cygwin64\usr\local\hadoop\htemp\mapred\local\taskTracker\cyg_server to 0700
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:691)
```

I have tried to change the permission, but it didn't work for me. Any solution?

```
chmod 0700 "c:\cygwin64\usr\local\hadoop\htemp\mapred\local\taskTracker\cyg_server"
```

Comment: my hadoop version is 1.2.1

Comment: looks like the jar files its attempting to execute cannot be found, or are not executable.